# Laravel route configuration acting strange

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have the following routes set up in my Laravel 4 application:

```
Route::get('/news', 'NewsController@index');
Route::get('/news/{slug}', 'NewsController@view');
```

In my `NewsController.php` file, I have the appropriate actions set up that return views. Now, when I browse to `/news`, I get an error message like so:

> Some mandatory parameters are missing ("slug") to generate a URL for route "get /news/{slug}

and when I browse to `/news/test-post` it all works fine.

What's weird is that if I comment out the route for `/news/{slug}` and browse to `/news`, this error gets thrown:

> Unknown action [NewsController@view].

even though the route for `/news` doesn't touch the `view` action, it uses `index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you haven't defined a RESTful controller routing before? Like:

```
Route::controller('/news', 'NewsController');
```

If you have, put the *Route::get* before the *Route::controller*. Otherwise I don't really know whats wrong, I couldn't reproduce the error with your setup.

Comment: I set up the same Routes and this controller, it works without any problems: http://pastebin.com/SZRwxJGc

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Is there maybe a cache or something that needs to be cleared? Although `debug` is set to true in my config.

Comment: What happens if you add the catch-all method for missing methods to the controller? [link](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#handling-missing-methods)

Comment: That never gets called since Laravel is using the `/news/{slug}` route instead of `/news` for the `/news` URL. I've also posted on the Laravel forums so hopefully someone can spot what's wrong on there :)